# Problems with aggregated CSS

Tags: 8, css-js-aggregation

I activated aggregate CSS on my local development and on a remote testing environment without any problems. Now on staging the aggregation of CSS files causes trouble: on some pages the styling looks correct but on random pages it is completely broken. The HTML sometimes shows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/?p0upgh" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/?p0upgh" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/?p0upgh" media="print" />
```

Sometimes some of the aggregated files seems not to be inserted via HTML meaning: there are no  Tags or just one - some of the stylesheets are missing.

I checked folder permissions: sites/default/files and sites/default/files/css have 777 as chmod values. The owner and the group of the folders and files belong to the correct folder and CSS are aggregated in sites/default/files/css.

Does anyone has some hint for me what my cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was connected to this: https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2914259

I am not quite sure what exactly was the problem but when I went to the status report page I realized the error message

```
Entity/field definitions
Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
Paragraph

- The Published field needs to be updated.
```

I implemented the update function

```
_update_function() {
  try {
    $entityUpdateManager = \Drupal::service('entity.definition_update_manager');
    $entityUpdateManager->applyUpdates();
  }
  catch (EntityStorageException $e) {
    print_r($e);
  }
}
```

run update and the problems with the aggregated css disappeared.